# Upgrade Jenkins within a Kubernetes container without losing my data?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have a container deployed in a pod by Kubernetes running Jenkins.  The container is mounted with a persistent storage volume (AWS Elastic File Store) that's currently storing all of the Jenkins instance's user, configuration, job configurations, etc.

I need to update Jenkins.  Normally when I do this, the process wipes out the storage, since the whole container gets re-launched.  However, I need to figure out how to do this without losing the data.

How do I update Jenkins without losing the info on the storage volume attached to the container?

Comment: Please provide details on how you deployed jenkins (yaml manifests, helm charts, ...)

Comment: I'm more looking for a description of how to do this in general, not so much how to fix my specific situation, since I'm kind of stabbing in the dark in terms of how to properly set this up.